# Find palindromes in list

Tags: java, algorithm, palindrome

Assume we have a list of integers, for example:

```
L = [13,13,4,13,4,2]
```

I want to find the set of all palindromes, where each palindrome is a sub-list of `L` containing contiguous integers. For the above list that would be:

```
S = {[13], [4], [2], [13,13], [13,4,13], [4,13,4]}
```

Because the inverse of `L` would be `L' = [2,4,13,4,13,13]`, and every element of `S` appears in `L'` in the correct order.

How can I find the set of all palindromes in general? My naive approach would be to check if each element of the power set of `L` appears in `L'`, but this is inefficient and I am sure that there is a better solution.

Comment: Note that you don't need to check all sub lists (why?). Hint: What can you learn about `L` when you checking: `[[13],[13,13,4],[13,13,4,13,4],[13,4,13,4,2],[13,4,2],[2]]`?

Answer (score 2):

I think my solution is pretty similar to solution from **MC Emperor**, but I focused on not creating temporary objects like lists.

I select sub-arrays of given array using `left` and `right` indices and check it for palindrome.

```
public static Set<List<Integer>> findAllPalindromes(int[] arr) {
    Set<List<Integer>> res = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    for (int length = 1; length < arr.length; length++)
        for (int left = 0, right = left + length - 1; right < arr.length; left++, right++)
            if (isPalindrome(arr, left, right))
                res.add(sublist(arr, left, right));

    return res;
}
```

This method check is given sub-array palindrome or not:

```
private static boolean isPalindrome(int[] arr, int left, int right) {
    for (; left < right; left++, right--)
        if (arr[left] != arr[right])
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

This method create separate list for given sub-array:

```
private static List<Integer> sublist(int[] arr, int left, int right) {
    List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>(right - left);

    for (; left <= right; left++)
        res.add(arr[left]);

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two steps to do that.

First, you'll need to find all sublists within the list:

```
List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(13, 13, 4, 13, 4, 2);

List<List<Integer>> subLists = new ArrayList<>();
for (int subListSize = 1; subListSize < input.size(); subListSize++) {
    for (int startIndex = 0; startIndex < input.size() - subListSize + 1; startIndex++) {
        List<Integer> subList = input.subList(startIndex, startIndex + subListSize);
        subLists.add(subList);
    }
}
// Also test the whole list:
subLists.add(input);
```

Then you need to check for each element if the list is a palindrome. To test if a list is a palindrome, element `n` must be compared to element `listSize - 1 - n`.

We only need to check half of the elements.

```
static boolean isPalindrome(List<Integer> subList) {
    for (int i = 0; i < subList.size() / 2; i++) {
        if (!Objects.equals(subList.get(i), subList.get(subList.size() - 1 - i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you want to remove duplicates, then you can put the elements into a `Set`.